# How can i change the font and the background color of a webpage for two types of users

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sass

I am trying to integrate a template.  I have this requirement from the client:

The user space will have a blue background.

The professional user space will have a orange background.

How can I apply a condition so that each color of the background can be changed, depending on weather the user is a normal user(blue) or a professional user(orange).

Comment: Please read [mcve] and add your code into your question

Comment: make 2 css one for the normal user and one for admin. you can do this with an if statement in php

Comment: yeah i figure that i will make 2 css files but i was wondering how i'll call the style-sheet depending on the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a query string to your url and load the stylesheet wanted for each specific usertype:

Login and and the user get either of these urls

website.com?view=professional

website.com?view=regular

```
if (window.location.search.indexOf('?view=professional') === 0)
  document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="professionalStylesheet.css" />');
else
  document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="regularStylesheet.css" />');
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the two classes in your css, then use `classList.toggle('classname')` in your javascript to switch for each user

Comment: but how it'll detect the type of the user ? that's my main concern

Comment: How do you set/get your user data? Are you fetching from an api?